# How to shuffle multiple files and save different files?

Tags: shell, shuffle

I have three files as:

> file1 file2 file3
>
> A　　B　　C
>
> D　　E　　F
>
> G　　H　　I

The lines in each file relate to each other.
Thus, I want to generate shuffled files as:

> file1.shuf file2.shuf file3.shuf
>
> G　　　　　H　　　　I
>
> D　　　　　E　　　　F
>
> A　　　　　B　　　　C

I often face this kind of problem and I always write a small script in Ruby or Python, but I thought it can be solved by some simple shell commands.
Could you suggest any simple ways to do this by shell commands or a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a simple script that does what you want. Specify all the input
files on the command line. It assumes all of the files have the same
number of lines.

First it creates a list of numbers and shuffles it. Then it combines
those numbers with each input file, sorts that, and removes the numbers.
Thus, each input file is shuffled in the same order.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Temp file to hold shuffled order
shuffile=$(mktemp)

# Create shuffled order
lines=$(wc -l < "$1")
digits=$(printf "%d" $lines | wc -c)
fmt=$(printf "%%0%d.0f" $digits)
seq -f "$fmt" $lines | shuf > $shuffile

# Shuffle each file in same way
for fname in "$@"; do
    paste $shuffile "$fname" | sort | cut -f 2- > "$fname.shuf"
done

# Clean up
rm $shuffile
```